# How do I make sure that iPod 2G users cant buy my game in iTunes?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes, info.plist

I am making a game for iOS and it is almost finished, it runs smoothly on all devices except for the iPod Touch 2G.

I want to make sure that people with this device can't buy the game from appstore by accident or at least give them a pop-up warning when they try to buy it, saying that there can be performance issues.

I heard it's possible to exclude a device through the `info.plist` but I cant figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, You cant prevent them from buying but you can add a note/disclaimer that the App will not work properly on iPod touch 2G. You can also detect the device as iPod 2G and display a warning when the App is run by the user.

Comment: I would like the note to appear before the user buys it, instead of people buying it and getting a bad experience

Comment: I meant add a note in the App description. I'm pretty sure that people read the description before buying the App.

Comment: It is my experience that the average user checks the screenshots and decides upon that. I heard that it is possible to put some restraints on devices through the info.plist, just cant figure out how

Answer (score 0):

the biggest difference (in typical runtime contexts) is the amount of physical memory.

in some cases, you can add support for the device by reducing the amount of memory you use.

the next to affect average apps is likely to be the processor speed.

investing some time into tuning your app to use less memory and reducing your cpu usage will work in most (but not all!) cases.

alternative:
the device is already out of the ios update cycle, you could require a minimum ios version (4.3 or greater).

Comment: the iOS thing is a good idea, but so many people are still running on iOS 4.0 and we really want to support those devices.
We only want to exclude iPod 2G and heard it was possible programaticly